# Issue related to getting data from UnKnown EntityType

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have web-application in MVC with entity-framework..

I have following code:

```
MotionSoftEntities msEntity = new MotionSoftEntities();
var resultData = msEntity.REP_MM_DEMOGRAPHIC.AsEnumerable();
```

Above code gets data from `REP_MM_DEMOGRAPHIC` Entity dataTable.

now the problem is that, i want to get data from table which is not known at compile time. is it possible something like follows :

```
private void GetData(string tableName)
        {
            MotionSoftEntities msEntity = new MotionSoftEntities();
            var resultData = msEntity.tableName.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

the table name will know at runtime..
how can i achieve it??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need dynamic SQL for cases like this.  Entity framework allows you to query build dynamic SQL

for eg:-

```
using (var context = new YourContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.SqlCommand( 
        "SELECT * FROM dbo.<<Your table name goes here>>");
}
```

You can now pass the table name here dynamically.